# Access variable outside controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to access or rather use a variable which was modified and initialised in my controller, outside that controller as a regular variable.

here is the controller:

```
 my.app.controller('queryCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
var tempAstData={
    'rightNode': 'longitude = 72.8604836',
    'leftNode': {
        'rightNode': 'latitude = 19.1738427',
        'leftNode': "fence_brand_name = 'taco'",
        'centerOperator': 'AND'
    },
    'centerOperator': 'AND'
}
// some functions on it
}]);
 //normal javascript 
// want to use tempAstData here as plain java script in this same file....
//this part is not a controller or anyway related t angular js . This is plane java script.
```

I am new to angular, any help is appreciated ty.

Comment: Since your variable tempAstData is not an angular scope variable you can define it in global and use anywhere accross

Comment: You could define your variable outside of your controller so this way you can either access it from the controller scope or above it.

Comment: You might wanna use `$rootScope` so it can be globally accessible all over your app or wanna try using `factory` or `service` then injecting it to whatever controller you wanna use

Comment: save in global environment, like window.tempAstData and use it anywhere in same window

Comment: but if i do declare temAstData gloally then, the changes I make to tempAstData in my controller are not reflected on it.

Comment: @Subhash you need to declare tempAsData out of controller scope with "var" (`var tempAsData = {}`) and use it inside controller without "var" (`tempAsData = {someKey : 'SomeStringValue'}`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Subhash in a comment in this question he has 3 assync methods in your controller. Then he needs to manipulate your tempAstData variable after this assync methods:

> @trichetriche I have 3 asyn methods in my controllers that hits server
>   with POST request. I didn't post it here to avoid complications.To be
>   precise i want to access that tempAstData in my html file with a
>   script tag  new Treant(tempAstData)

In this case i suggest to use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to wait all promises and after this call a method that manipulates tempAstData, like this:

```
my.app.controller('queryCtrl', ['$scope','$http', '$q',function($scope, $http, $q) {

    var wrapMethod = function (parameter) {
        // do something with parameter
    }

    var tempAstData={
       'rightNode': 'longitude = 72.8604836',
       'leftNode': {
           'rightNode': 'latitude = 19.1738427',
           'leftNode': "fence_brand_name = 'taco'",
           'centerOperator': 'AND'
       },
       'centerOperator': 'AND'
    }

    var promises = [];

    // add promises returned by assync methods to a array
    promises.push(assyncMethod1());
    promises.push(assyncMethod2());
    promises.push(assyncMethod3());


    // wait all promises to be resolved
    $q.all(promises).then(function () {

        // call wrap method with 'normal' JavaScript code previously in a script tag
        wrapMethod(tempAstData);

    })

}]);
```

@Subhash Please, edit your question and add the complete information to clarify for another users

Answer (score 0):

```
var myGlobalVariable = null;
 my.app.controller('queryCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
var tempAstData={
    'rightNode': 'longitude = 72.8604836',
    'leftNode': {
        'rightNode': 'latitude = 19.1738427',
        'leftNode': "fence_brand_name = 'taco'",
        'centerOperator': 'AND'
    },
    'centerOperator': 'AND'
}

myGlobalVariable = tempAstData;
// some functions on it
}]);

alert(myGlobalVariable);

 //normal javascript 
// want to use tempAstData here as plain java script in this same file....
//this part is not a controller or anyway related t angular js . This is plane java script.
```

Comment: use of global variables is not the right solution, You should never expose anything with global variables.

Comment: and this way the alert box will show null. As javascript and angular both are async.

Comment: I didn't say it was the right thing to do @ChandraPrakashVariyani. I am just giving him an answer. And Suhash, did you try it ? Because you don't have any async methods here.

Comment: and @Subhash, I read that you need it for another library in full Javascript. It's okay, you can use it in a controller, what you need to avoid is JQuery because of the `$` selector.

Comment: @trichetriche I have 3 asyn methods in my controllers that hits server with POST request. I didn't post it here to avoid complications.To be precise i want to access that tempAstData in my html file with a script tag
<script > new Treant(tempAstData) </script>

Comment: if it is so, then you should have cleared this thing in ur answer, that its not ryt way.

Comment: Oh ok sorry then. What about my second comment ?

Comment: @ChandraPrakashVariyani Given that he knows what he wants, I assumed he would know that. I am here to provide answers to questions, not telling people what to do with their application. But I get your point though. I'll try to be more precise.

Comment: @Subhash you can wrap your code in the `script` tag into a method inside the controller or inside a service method. Then after your promises are resolved you call this method.

Comment: @BrunoPeres I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

use `$rootScope` for referencing the data globally in angular way

```
my.app.controller('queryCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$rootScope',function($scope,$http,$rootScope){  

var tempAstData={
    'rightNode': 'longitude = 72.8604836',
    'leftNode': {
    'rightNode': 'latitude = 19.1738427',
    'leftNode': "fence_brand_name = 'taco'",
    'centerOperator': 'AND'
    },
    'centerOperator': 'AND'
  }

 $rootScope.tempAstData = tempAstData;
// some functions on it
}]);
```

then you may use the `$rootScope.tempAstData` to other controllers

```
my.app.controller('otherCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$rootScope',function($scope,$http,$rootScope){  
 console.log($rootScope.tempAstData) 
})
```

Comment: I dont want to use it in other controller. I want to use it outside that controller as plane javascript. I am using a tree visualisation library treant.js , which require a json in particular format. So, process it in my controller and want to use that data. Since the library treant.js is written purely in javascript, using both angular and treant is difficult.

Comment: make a simple variable out of it, the classic `var tempAstData = null` first then reference it inside your controller and then you can use it ready for your tree visualization